# how use sessions and store value in a session and use for login sysytem

Tags: asp.net, session

i am trying to create an custom   login process and for this a want use sessions but i cant find any source for that how i can use sessions in asp.net MVC please guide me how i can use sessions i just check from them that user log out or not so he can be able to access on dashboard without log in again. thanks in advance.

```
Session["user"] = profile.userName;
                var admin = db.userProfiles.Where(x => x.userName == user.userName && x.password == user.password && x.admin==1).FirstOrDefault();
                if(admin==null)
                {
                    if (Session["user"] != null)
                    {
                        ViewBag.userName = user.userName;
                        return View();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       return RedirectToAction("login");
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    if (Session["user"] != null)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       return RedirectToAction("login");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reinventing the wheel. Have you considered using the built-in Identity and authentication schemes?

Create an ASP.NET Core app with user data protected by authorization
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data

Building a simple ToDo application with ASP.NET Identity and associating Users with ToDoes
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes/

Comment: i did this in the sense of learning.. can u guide me what is the good way for learn asp.net MVC.?